# Let $ S_{n} $ be the $ n $th sum of $ a_n $, and we know that $ S_n a_n=4^{-n} $. Find $ a_n $ .

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ S_{n} $ be the $ n $th sum of a sequence $ \{a_n\} $, and we know that $ S_n a_n=4^{-n} $. Find $ a_n $ .

Also the question can be rewritten by $ S_{n}(S_{n}-S_{n-1})=4^{-n} $， find $ S_n $.